# Miscalculating recursive state probability

Tags: python, recursion, probability, solver

```
def get_dir(state, max_depth):
    #Possible directions and their corresponding scores so far
    paths = {'w':1,'a':1,'s':1,'d':1}
    #Rate each direction
    for dir in paths:
        #Takes a game state and a direction as input and returns
        #a list of all possible states that could occur from moving in that direction
        children = successors(state, dir)
        if children:
            children = [children[0][:10], children[1][:10]]
            #Weight the probability of the each state depending on if a 2 on or a 4 was spawned
            weights = {0:.9,1:.1}
            for section in weights:
                for board in children[section]:
                                                                 #PROBLEM HERE
                    paths[dir] += rank_branch(board, max_depth,  (weights[section]*(1/(num_empty(board)))))
        else:
            paths[dir] = False
```

I am using the above function to pick a direction to move in 2048. I am trying to weight the heuristic ranking of each state by the probability that we will be able to reach that state.

To do this, at each ply I multiply the probability of the spawning a tile with that number on it(.9 for a t and .1 for a 4) by the number of places it could have spawned(the number of empty tiles).

My code for this:

```
weights[section]*(1/(num_empty(board))))
```

When I print out the probability variable, it's always to high. It constantly thinks that our odds of being able to make it to a given state are greater than the really are?

Comment: Is this in Python 2.x, by any chance?

Comment: Yes, but I imported division from __future__

Comment: Then could you cut this down to a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with inputs and expected and actual outputs? As it stands, it's not clear why you think there's a problem, and therefore very difficult to help you find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If each board in the children variable is a state after a random tile has been spawned, wouldn't you need to add 1 to the number of empty tiles since the spot where the new tile spawned was empty before it spawned there?

```
weights[section]*(1/(num_empty(board)+1)))
```

That being said, calling  a function each time around seems to be a bit silly since the probability of getting a state when moving a given direction is the same for all successors(except for the difference when spawning 2 tiles vs 4 tiles).

A better way to calculate the probability would be to just count the successors and figure out what the odds of being picked out of that pool would be.

```
prob = {0:9/(len(children[0])*9)+len(children[1]),1:1/(len(children[0])*9)+len(children[1])}
```

Comment: Wow, Thanks. Adding 1 seems to have fixed the problem. Could you explain  why just counting up the successors gives the probability of state?

Comment: @Jian Tsurugi All states where a 2 is spawned are equally likely to be chosen since the number of merges is always the same when moving in one direction. The new tile is spawned AFTER the merges take place. 2 tiles are 9 times as likely to spawn as 4 tile, so I divide  9 when calculating the probability of a 2 tile spawning, and divide 1 when calculating the odds of a 4 tile spawning.